# C#: Call overloaded method in external assembly from generic

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

I have a project that references a 3rd party c# assembly containing several overloaded instance methods.  I want to invoke one of these methods via a generic in my code, calling the instance method whose parameter type matches the type of the generic:

```
void GetVal<T>(ref T val)
{
    VendorLib v = new VendorLib();
    v.GetVal(ref val); 
}

// error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ref T' to 'ref bool'
```

The closest I have come is through the use of a dynamic variable, but this results in a runtime exception as the parameter d resolves to bool even though the type of the generic is ulong, thereby binding the incorrect method:

```
class MyClass
{
    void Caller()
    {
        ulong val = 0;
        this.GetValue<ulong>(ref val);
    }

    void GetValue<T>(ref T val)
    {
        dynamic d = val; 
        GetValDynamic(ref d);
    }

    void GetValDynamic(ref dynamic val)
    {
        VendorLib v = new VendorLib();
        v.GetVal(ref val);
    }
}
```

Exception:
Result Message: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException : The best overloaded method match for 'VendorLib.GetVal(ref bool)' has some invalid arguments

The vendor library contains several GetVal overloads, of which `GetVal(ref bool)` is one and `GetVal(ref ulong)` another.

Why is the correct method not being bound?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to check typeof(T) and call the respective method manually then reflection can work. Something like this...

```
  public class MyVendorLibWrapper
  {
    private readonly VendorLib vendorLib;

    public MyVendorLibWrapper()
    {
      this.vendorLib = new VendorLib();
    }

    public T GetValue<T>()
    {
      MethodInfo method = typeof(VendorLib)
        .GetMethod("GetVal", new Type[] { typeof(T).MakeByRefType() });

      object[] arguments = new object[] { default(T) };
      method.Invoke(this.vendorLib, arguments);
      return (T)arguments[0];
    }
  }
```

And called something like this...

```
MyVendorLibWrapper wrapper = new MyVendorLibWrapper();
int x = wrapper.GetValue<int>();
```

Comment: Note that answer provided by garryp is sensible and can be improved by making the IMyClass generic (IMyClass<T>). At that point you can easily inject/create an instance per type assuming one exists (IMyClass<int>, etc.)

Comment: This worked well. Run time performance is surprisingly good, in fact no worse than a version without reflection.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. You could likely increase performance by caching MethodInfo intoa dictionary (Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>)

Comment: Yes, that's what I did.  Even without this, however, the performance was reasonably good.

Answer (score 1):

`val` is a `dynamic`, not a `bool` or a `ulong`. It is the wrong type. By using `dynamic` you are just cheating yourself out of the compile-time checking and just getting an error at runtime instead.

Looking at the way this code works the only purpose of generics and dynamic is to find a way to pass either a bool or a ulong to GetVal(...). From your code it looks like the only method that might need to be public is Caller(), in which case you can hide all this behind a common interface.

```
class MyClassULong : IMyClass
{
    void Caller()
    {
        ulong val = 0;
        this.GetValue(ref val);
    }

    void GetValue(ulong val)
    {
        VendorLib v = new VendorLib();
        v.GetVal(ref val);
    }

}

class MyClassBool : IMyClass
{
    void Caller()
    {
        bool val = false;
        this.GetValue(ref val);
    }

    void GetValue(bool val)
    {
        VendorLib v = new VendorLib();
        v.GetVal(ref val);
    }

}

public interface IMyClass
{
    void Caller();
}
```

Then any code invoking Caller() would be written against IMyClass, and therefore wouldn't care which implementation you used.

```
public void CallIt(IMyClass myClass)
{
    myClass.Caller();
}
```

There are lots of patterns to get round this type of problem. For a better understanding you really need to spend a good deal of time reading about OOP in C#, and spend time coding.

Comment: I see. More generally, then, is there an established pattern for solving the problem of calling the appropriate overload from a generic?

Comment: See my post. Its difficult to really give you a clear answer here, but hopefully this should help a bit.

Comment: Thanks, the only downside compared with the reflection approach is having to declare a class for each type. But fine if you don't need to support many types.